# Why doesn't a specific type satisfy an empty interface in Go?

Tags: go, interface

I have a simple interface in Go:

```
type ReadTimeSeriesRepository interface {
    GetTimeSeries(database string, params any) (*models.TimeSeriesResponse, domain.Error)
}
```

As you can see, params is of type any (interface{})

So, I have the following implementation:

```
type influxV2Client struct {
    client influxdb2.Client
}

func (c *influxV2Client) GetTimeSeries(database string, params models.BaseTimeSeriesQuery) (*models.TimeSeriesResponse, domain.Error) {
    queryAPI := c.client.QueryAPI(config.Cfg.InfluxOrg)
    // Patch
    query := `from(bucket: "417")
    |> range(start: 1706745600, stop: 1706828400)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "energy")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "clean")`
    // End Patch
    result, err := queryAPI.Query(context.Background(), query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error: ", err.Error()) // Pending proper management
    }

    // Use Next() to iterate over query result lines
    for result.Next() {
        // Observe when there is new grouping key producing new table
        if result.TableChanged() {
            fmt.Printf("table: %s\n", result.TableMetadata().String())
        }
        // read result
        fmt.Printf("row: %s\n", result.Record().String())
    }
    if result.Err() != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Query error: %s\n", result.Err().Error())
    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

As you can see, in this case params is of type models.BaseTimeSeriesQuery which is:

```
type BaseTimeSeriesQuery struct {
    Measurement []string          `json:"measurement"`
    Start       string            `json:"start"`
    Stop        *string           `json:"stop"`
    Tags        map[string]string `json:"tags"`
    TagOperator string            `json:"tag_operator"`
    Fields      []string          `json:"fields"`
}
```

As I understand it, this type must satisfy the empty interface (I understand that any type satisfies it). But later I get this error:

```
cannot use timeSerieRepositoryInfluxV2 (variable of type *"github.com/diegolatorre16/go-time-series/app/repositories/time_series".influxV2Client) as ports.ReadTimeSeriesRepository value in argument to services.GetTimeSeries: *"github.com/diegolatorre16/go-time-series/app/repositories/time_series".influxV2Client does not implement ports.ReadTimeSeriesRepository (wrong type for method GetTimeSeries)
        have GetTimeSeries(string, models.BaseTimeSeriesQuery) (*models.TimeSeriesResponse, "github.com/diegolatorre16/go-time-series/app/domain".Error)
        want GetTimeSeries(string, any) (*models.TimeSeriesResponse, "github.com/diegolatorre16/go-time-series/app/domain".Error)
```

I'm pretty new to Go, I guess I have some confusion in the way interfaces work in Go

Comment: See the assignability rules: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability In short: for a function value to be assignable to a variable of function type its signature must **match entirely**.

Comment: See also https://blog.merovius.de/posts/2018-06-03-why-doesnt-go-have-variance-in/

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go. This wouldn't work in any language. The interface says `GetTimeSeries("foo", 0)` is legal. But this call clearly doesn't work for influxV2Client.

Answer (score 2):

As the err said "influxV2Client does not implement ports.ReadTimeSeriesRepository", to implement ReadTimeSeriesRepository, influxV2Client should be defined like this:

`func (c *influxV2Client) GetTimeSeries(database string, params any) (*models.TimeSeriesResponse, domain.Error) { ... }`

In this way, you can use GetTimeSeries() the same way.